# Chromedriver has stopped working and says Driver info: chromedriver=81.0.4044.69 even though I have 81.0.4044.138 installed

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

```
 Ignoring uncaught error SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81
 (Driver info: chromedriver=81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}),platform=Mac OS X 10.15.4 x86_64)
```

Inside `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/` I have:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 account1  staff     94690  5 May 23:12 chrome-response.xml
-rwxr-xr-x   1 account1  staff  14786468 15 Mar 05:40 chromedriver_81.0.4044.138
-rw-r--r--   1 account1  staff   7019279  5 May 23:12 chromedriver_81.0.4044.138.zip
-rw-r--r--   1 account1  staff    397989  5 May 23:12 gecko-response.json
-rwxr-xr-x   1 account1  staff   5259056 10 Oct  2019 geckodriver-v0.26.0
-rw-r--r--   1 account1  staff   2006880  5 May 23:12 geckodriver-v0.26.0.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 account1  staff       566  5 May 23:12 update-config.json
```

I have Version 81.0.4044.138 installed as I can see in `chrome://settings/help`

I've no idea where it's getting `81.0.4044.69` from...

Comment: I do see that version in the node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml but don't know why it would be picking that version?

Comment: Weird, I restarted my machine and it fixed it. npm link messing up or nvm. Who knows?